# is it possible to use data from a website that i don't really have access to for my cordova/phonegap app

Tags: database, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm in the process of making an app for my assessment at uni using cordova/phonegap and was just wondering if its possible for me to use data from a my unis ecom website for my app without having any back-end access to it, so like images/prices/descriptions...synced to my app?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is certainly possible, because Cordova means working via Javascript and a HTML5 Rendering Engine. It is with some reservations entirely possible to load data from an webserver and use it in an App.

The only thing is to ask, whether it is also a smart-choice. If you want your app not to break when the data from the website gets changed (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot )

Also the server can somewhat prevent access of data from contextes outside of the webpage, especially if TSL/HTTPS connection is offered and content is only available after authentication.

Yet anyway its the magic of Javascript to be very good in doing things with web/online resources and displaying HTML5. Cordova and PHonegap is hence imo much better than the very challenging JAVA-Dalvik and IOs native programming that one would have to use else

Answer (score 0):

Likely not,

[Google and Apple frowns on using apps as wrappers for websites.](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005a)

> *Quote [Google Developer Program Policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) - **Spam and Placement in the Store***
>
> > Do not post an app where the primary functionality is to:
> >
> > - Drive affiliate traffic to a website or
> > - Provide a webview of a website not owned or administered by you (unless you have permission from the website owner/administrator to do so)

And

> *Quote [Apple iTunes Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) - **2.12***
>
> > Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected